# Using Python to calculate sum in CSV row

Tags: python-2.7

I want to calculate sum of each row with Python in Excel file saved as .csv

like this example:
[image: example]

Comment: `.csv` is not excel file, it is... csv. So it should be read with `csv.csvreader`

Comment: how to create a new column in order to store each row‘s result？THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
import csv
with open('foo.csv') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in spamreader:
        sum = 0
        for i in row:
            sum += int(i)
    print(sum)
```

Comment: thanks sharing，it works but only for the last row，how to create a new column in order to store each row‘s result？