# Use python to calculate data in CSV

Tags: python-2.7

Like the sample, first I want to read the CSV file and sum each row and store the result in new column (which need to create).

sample:
[image: sample]

Comment: This question deserves answers that show as much effort as you expended when you wrote that question, which is **zero**. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially [ask] before posting your next question here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Python to calculate sum in CSV row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42738644/using-python-to-calculate-sum-in-csv-row)

Answer (score -1):

```
import csv

new_rows = []

with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
        row = [int(val) for val in row]
        row.append(sum(row))
        new_rows.append(row)

with open('file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    csv.writer(csvfile).writerows(new_rows)
```

turning file.csv from

```
1,2
3,4
```

into

```
1,2,3
3,4,7
```